# How do I set the root directory for links while editing offline?

Tags: html

I'm making a website that I used to edit directly online on Neocities, but due to some problems, I'm looking to switch my editing to local offline. But I can't make my links point correctly to their targets, such as the favicon or my css files because locally, "/" doesn't point to the root.

Is there any program that allows me to set a folder as the root directory so these links can point properly? I'm currently trying Notepad++ but I haven't found a way to do so.

I know I could put the full path as "C:\folder\folder\file.css" for examle, but that would mean I'd have to edit the html of every single of my many pages and then re-edit them when I upload them online, and that's very undesirable. I need a way to preview the html locally without changing any paths, so my favicon link, for example, which currently is href="/favicon.png" can stay unchanged on all the pages. I could remove the "/" but then it wouldn't work for any pages within subfolders, and there's a lot of those in my project.

It's possible that I'm just missing some simple detail but I'm really just very much a beginner to making websites in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a local web server to serve the contents of your root directory at a domain like `http://localhost:8080`. So rather than opening `index.html` in the browser you visit that URL instead.

There are a bunch of simple web servers you can use - my favourite for purposes like this is the NPM package `http-server`. It requires Node to be installed.

1. Install node
2. Install http-server by executing `npm install -g http-server` in your Terminal
3. Run the http-server by navigate to the website root folder and run `http-server` in your Terminal

`http-server` will produce an output that will tell you where to access the site.

```
Starting up http-server, serving ./

http-server version: 14.1.0

Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://localhost:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```